# jQuery - display div based on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, selection

Possible solution but cannot get it to work:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[name="q10"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
    var flag=0;

    $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
      if($(this).val()==1 || $(this).val()==2 ){
        $("#disagree").show();
         flag++;
      }
      else if(($(this).val()==3 || $(this).val()==4) && flag==0)
        $("#agree").show();
    });
    }
  });
});
```

I have a page with 10 questions on - with a response scale for each question, as follows:

```
<div id="rq1" class="row" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
<div class="col1">1.</div>
<div class="col2a">Question text</div>
<div class='colans'>
      <input  name='q1' value='4' id='q1a4' type='radio' onclick='mand();' />
</div>
<div class='colans'>
      <input  name='q1' value='3' id='q1a3' type='radio' onclick='mand();' />
</div>
<div class='colans'>
      <input  name='q1' value='2' id='q1a2' type='radio' onclick='mand();' />
</div>
<div class='colans'>
      <input  name='q1' value='1' id='q1a1' type='radio' onclick='mand();' />
</div>
<div class='colans'>
      <input  name='q1' value='-1' id='q1a-1' type='radio' onclick='mand();' />
</div>
</div>
```

The above replicates for each of the 10 questions q1 through q10.

At the end of the 10 questions, I have two `textareas` where users can write comments, However, the first `textarea` needs to appear if a user selects **ANY** response with a value of either 2 or 1.  The second `textarea` needs to appear if a user selects **ANY** response with a value of either 4 or 3 but hasn't selected a response with a value of 2 or 1.

Finally, I need the jQuery to run once the user has answered the last question, question 10 - it's at this point I need the code to fire.

In the past, I have manually created Javascript code for each response and checked but I wondered if there was a neater, more concise way using jQuery?

Comment: Can you tell me what error you got in above solution?

Comment: The above code, when implemented only checks 1 question - I need to to check questions 1 to 10 to see what the respondent has selected.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have not formatted code well but I guess this will help you.Also I checked the last answer given and I guess everytime accessing this object is not that good idea.But its just my opinion. All the best :-)

```
`var myradio = $('input[name=nettype]');
var nettype = myradio.filter(':checked').val();

if(nettype ==1 || nettype ==2 )
{
 $("#myTextArea1").show();
 $("#myTextArea2").hide();
}
else if(nettype ==3 || nettype == 4 )
{
 $("#myTextArea2").show();
 $("#myTextArea1").hide();
}`
```

For comment you have added to previous answer you can add following code

```
`if ( $('.myClass').filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() != '';
    }).length == 0
 )
 {
  /* code to run when all are empty */

 }`
```

you can add this classname myClass to your textboxes so that when all textboxes will be answered then you can fire code for radiobutton. :-)

Comment: thanks but again, this only offers a part solution - see my response to rps below.

Comment: I have edited my answer. This will check all your answers if you will use same class name for all of your html controls which you are using for answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag=0;

$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
  if($(this).val()==1 || $(this).val()==2 ){
    $("#myTextArea1").show();
     flag++;
  }
  else if(($(this).val()==3 || $(this).val()==4) && flag==0)
    $("#myTextArea2").show();
});
```

fire this code when the last question is answered!!

update:
   this is the full code...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#disagree").hide();
   $("#agree").hide();

   $("input[name='q10']").click(function() {

    $("#disagree").hide();
    $("#agree").hide();

    var flag=0;

    $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {

       if($(this).val()==1 || $(this).val()==2 ){

           $("#disagree").show();
           $("#agree").hide();
           flag++;
       }

      else if(($(this).val()==3 || $(this).val()==4) && flag==0)

           $("#agree").show();
   });
 });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks @rps - that is fine for simply showing the relevant text areas - the issue as follows:  1.  The second textarea can only be shown if the user hasn't selected 1 & 2 for ANY of the 10 questions and I need the code to fire at once they have answered q10 (so it needs to check all questions in one go - not as they make a selection)

Comment: @Homer_J no, the above code doesnt need to be fired during answering of all the questiong, just fire it for the answering of the last question, that will do

Comment: Thanks @rps - just trying to implement now - question - will this question all questions from q1 to q10 even though I'm firing the code when the user selects an option for q10?

Comment: @Homer_J is the onclick itself  working? and does the code inside the if (checked) condition fire? why are you checking the "checked" condition sir? This is not a checkbox but a radio button , it will not get unchecked on clicking right?

Comment: I need to fire your jQuery code upon some clicking a response for q10 (hence why I am checking whether q10 is checked) - works fine as when I place an `alert` it fires correctly.  However, when I add your code it doesn't work.

Comment: @Homer_J try quoting the  values of the checkboxes $(this).val()=="1"

Comment: `$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
      flag++;
    });  alert(flag);` try this sir, you able to get the no. of checked radio buttons?

Comment: Hi @rps - as suspected, this code only checks on question - I need it to check all questions from 1 to 10 - not just the one I answered.  Sorry.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/rpss/E8vbr/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/rpss/E8vbr/4/) is the click event bound at document.ready()?